# Firebase lazy loading with rxjs

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, reactive-programming, angularfire2

I have the following code, to get the last chast messages:

```
const pageSize = 10;
this.notifier = new Subject<any>();
let last: Observable<any>;

let infiniteList = Observable

  // Use zip to combine the notifier's emissions with the last
  // child value:

  .zip(this.notifier, Observable.defer(() => last))

  // Use concatMap to emit a page of children into the
  // composed observable (note that first is used to complete
  // the inner list):

  .concatMap(([unused, last]) => this.af.database.list("chat_messages", {
      query: {

        // If there is a last value, start at that value but ask
        // for one more:

        limitToLast: last ? (pageSize + 1) : pageSize
      }
    })
    .first()
  )

  // Use scan to accumulate the page into the infinite list:

  .scan((acc, list) => {

    // If this isn't the initial page, the page was started
    // at the last value, so remove it from the beginning of
    // the list:

    if (acc.length > 0) {
      list.shift();
    }
    return acc.concat(list);
  }, [])

  // Use share so that the last observable (see below) doesn't
  // result in a second subscription:

  .share();

// Each time a page is emitted, map to its last child value so
// that it can be fed back into the composed infinite list:

last = infiniteList
  .map((list) => {
    list.reverse();
    if (list.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return list[list.length - 1].date_published;
  })
  .startWith(null);

infiniteList.subscribe((list) => {
  this.chatMessages = list;
});
this.notifier.next();
```

Whenever the user scrolls to the bottom of the list I do `this.notifier.next();` to read more from the chat history. 10 messages at a time.

**The problem**: the first 10 works great, but when I scroll to the bottom to read new data, I get the same information in the opposite order. For example, I had this:

> 1- Good
>
> 2- Fine, you?
>
> 10- Hi alL! How are you?
>
> ---scroll to the previous 10 message--
>
> 12-. Hi all! How are you?
>
> 13-. Fine, you?
>
> 14-. Good

Answer (score 3):

The following implementation should work just fine.

Note that the composed `last` observable uses `filter` to stop emitting values when it reaches the end (or the beginning, depending on your point of view) and the last key is the first element in the page.

Also, the page needs to be reversed - as Firebase always uses an ascending order - and the reversal should occur in the composed `pages` observable and the page needs to be copied as the reversal occurs in place.

```js
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import rxjs/add/observable/defer";
import rxjs/add/observable/zip";
import rxjs/add/operator/concatMap";
import rxjs/add/operator/filter";
import rxjs/add/operator/first";
import rxjs/add/operator/map";
import rxjs/add/operator/scan";
import rxjs/add/operator/share";
import rxjs/add/operator/startWith";

const pageSize = 100;
let notifier = new Subject<any>();
let last: Observable<any>;

let pages = Observable

  // Use zip to combine the notifier's emissions with the last
  // child value:

  .zip(notifier, Observable.defer(() => last))

  // Use concatMap to emit a page of children into the
  // composed observable (note that first is used to complete
  // the inner list):

  .concatMap(([unused, last], index) => this.af.database
    .list("chat_messages", {
      query: {
        endAt: last,
        limitToLast: (index === 0) ? pageSize : (pageSize + 1)
      }
    })
    .first()
  )

  // Use share so that the last observable (see below) doesn't
  // result in a second subscription:

  .share();

// Each time a page is emitted, map to its last child value so
// that it can be fed back into the composed infinite list:

last = pages
  .filter((page) => page.length > 0)
  .map((page) => page[0].$key)
  .startWith(undefined);

// Use scan to accumulate the pages into the infinite list. Copy
// the page - using slice - before reversing it:

let infiniteList = pages
  .scan((list, page) => {
    page = page.slice();
    page.reverse();
    if (list.length > 0) {
      page.shift();
    }
    return list.concat(page);
  }, []);

infiniteList.subscribe(observer);

// Each time the notifier emits, another page will be retrieved
// and added to the infinite list:

notifier.next();
notifier.next();
notifier.next();
```

This will only work reliably when using `orderByKey`. The Firebase SDK's `startAt` method supports an optional `key` parameter when ordering by child, value or priority. However, the `endAt` method is documented as only supporting `key` when ordering by priority. That means that paging using `endAt` and `orderByChild` will not be reliable - if the child values are not unique and there are multiple items with the same child value, paging will not always be possible.

Regarding realtime updates for the infinite list, that is more complicated, as the limit-based mechanism can easily see duplicate and missing items effected. However, it is reasonably simple to include realtime additions at the head of the list:

```js
let notifier = new Subject<any>();
let last: Observable<any>;

let pages = Observable
  .zip(notifier, Observable.defer(() => last))
  .concatMap(([unused, last], index) => this.af.database
    .list("chat_messages", {
      query: {
        endAt: last,
        limitToLast: (index === 0) ? pageSize : (pageSize + 1)
      }
    })
    .first()
  )
  .share();

last = pages
  .filter((page) => page.length > 0)
  .map((page) => page[0].$key)
  .startWith(undefined);

let tail = pages
  .scan((list, page) => {
    page = page.slice();
    page.reverse();
    if (list.length > 0) {
      page.shift();
    }
    return list.concat(page);
  }, []);

// When the first non-empty page is emitted, create an observable
// that watches items starting at the first item in the first page:

let head = pages
  .filter((page) => page.length > 0)
  .take(1)
  .switchMap((page) => this.af.database
    .list("chat_messages", {
      query: {
        startAt: page[page.length - 1].$key
      }
    })
  )
  .map((list) => list.slice(1));

// And combine that with the pages:

let infiniteList = Observable
  .combineLatest(
    head,
    tail,
    (head, tail) => head.concat(tail)
  );

infiniteList.subscribe(observer);

notifier.next();
notifier.next();
notifier.next();
```

Comment: After updating to your code (which seem more right), when going to the bottom of the list and using `next()` it shows the same chat messages over again

Comment: I've updated the answer. You need to copy the list before it's reversed - as the reversal is in-place.

Comment: Same output as I had in the beginning, it shows the same messages when using `emit.next()`, just in reversed order, instead of older messages

Comment: Did you test it? This is the observer output when I have 11 chat messages. http://i.imgur.com/V5zkKY0.png, Message 1 is the last item in the second array (which initiated when I scrolled to the bottom). Are you having the same output?

Comment: Just noticed that you have `date_published` in your code, but have not specified `orderByChild` in your query. I'm guessing that you just left it out of the snippet. Anyway, you can only page backwards when using keys, as only `startAt` supports the optional `key` parameter when using `orderByChild`. The code in the answer works fine when ordering by key.

Comment: I had to add `orderByKey: true` to my query and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey @cartant, it seem like real time is not working when using this. If someone adds a new message, the infiniteList subscription does't update, you have any solution for this?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Hey @cartant, the additional code should be replaced by `last` observable in the first code or additionally? because the code works with the `last` observable from the first code, I couldn't figure out how the `head` and `tail` are included in the first code

Comment: Updated the answer so the second snippet is complete.

Comment: Chat still not updating for new messages, real time is not working even after updating to the second snippet, what's missing?

Comment: It works fine for me. If it's not working for you, you have something to investigate/debug.

Comment: I've been debugging it for several hours - what is your `observer`?